# how to submit and post a search field using pl sql

Tags: html, sql, plsql, toad

i would like my button to be embedded within this cursor. so when a user inputs data onto the 'search_field' and clicks the button 'Unsuspend', the Process SCRIPT should run and post 3 different information (Student_no, Suspend_account, and Student_name ) onto my next page.

is there any java script i have to include if so please help. if not what can i do to run the process script.

--Process SCRIPT--

```
CURSOR C_STUDENTS(P_TERM VARCHAR2) IS
            SELECT SZRASPR_STUDENT_NO STUDENT,
                SZRASPR_PIDM PIDM,
                SZRASPR_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT SUSPEND 

                FROM SZRASPR
                WHERE SZRASPR_TERM_CODE = P_TERM
                AND SZRASPR_STUDENT_NO IN ('000925656');

        V_TERM VARCHAR(6) := '201600';
        V_STUDENT VARCHAR(10);
        V_PIDM INTEGER;
        V_OUTCOME INTEGER;
        V_STEP1_COUNT INTEGER;
        V_STEP3_COUNT INTEGER;
            TYPE Type5record IS RECORD(Type5rowid ROWID, StudentLog VARCHAR2(200));
            TYPE Type5table IS TABLE OF Type5record
            INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
            Type5delete Type5table;
            Type5empty Type5table;
            Type5count INTEGER := 0; 

    BEGIN
        FOR V_STUDENTS IN C_STUDENTS(V_TERM) LOOP
            V_STUDENT := NULL;
            V_STUDENT := V_STUDENTS.STUDENT;

            IF V_STUDENTS.SUSPENDED = 'Y' THEN 
            V_PIDM := NULL;
            V_PIDM := V_STUDENTS.PIDM;
            V_STEP1_COUNT := 0;


            UPDATE SZRASPR 
                SET SZRASPR_SUSPEND_ACOUNT = 'N', SZRASPR_SEN = 1
                WHERE SZRASPR_TERM_CODE = V_TERM
                AND SZRASPR_STUDENT_NO = V_STUDENT;
                V_STEP1_COUNT := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
            IF V_STEP1_COUNT > 0 THEN 
                COMMIT;
                END IF;


            V_OUTCOME := NULL;
            HWZKASPR.P_ASPIRETBRACCD(V_PIDM, V_OUTCOME);
            IF V_OUTCOME = 1 THEN 
                --
                SELECT ROWID INTO Type5delete(Type5count).Type5rowid
                FROM SZRASFN WHERE SZRASFN_TERM_CODE = V_TERM
                AND SZRASFN_STUDENT_NO = V_STUDENT
                AND SZRASFN_ACTIVITY_DATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE;
            END IF;
            Type5delete(Type5count).StudentLog := 'STUDENT:'||V_STUDENT
                                                    ||' Step1count:'||V_STEP1_COUNT
                                                    ||' Step2outcome:'||CASE WHEN V_OUTCOME = 1 THEN
                                                    'OK' ELSE 'NOT OK' END 
                                                    ||'Step3count:';
            Type5count := Type5count + 1;
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STUDENT:'||V_STUDENT||' NOT SUSPENDED IN THE FIRST PLACE!!');
        END IF;
        END LOOP;

        FOR i IN Type5delete.FIRST .. Type5delete.LAST LOOP
        -- 
        V_STEP3_COUNT := 0;
        IF Type5delete(i).Type5rowid IS NOT NULL THEN 
            DELETE FROM SZRASFN WHERE ROWID = Type5delete(i).Type5rowid;
            V_STEP3_COUNT := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
            COMMIT;
        END IF;

        --report on status of data 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Type5delete(i).StudentLog||V_STEP3_COUNT
                                ||CASE WHEN Type5delete(i).Type5rowid
                                IS NOT NULL THEN 
                                ' ROWID:'|| Type5delete(i).Type5rowid
                                END);
        END LOOP;
        Type5delete := Type5empty;


    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STUDENT:'||V_STUDENT|| 'Error Occured: '||SQLERRM
                                ||CHR(10)||'['||DMBS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE||']');
    END; 

    -- 





-- BUTTON CODE --   

 HTP.FORMOPEN ('goes_to_next_page', 'post');
        HTP.FORMTEXT (
                    cname        => 'search_field',
                    csize        => 25,
                    cmaxlength   => 9,
                --  cvalue       => ,
                    cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" placeholder="e.g. 000123456"');

        HTP.FORMSUBMIT ('', 'Unsuspend');
        HTP.FORMCLOSE;
```

Comment: HI Rahman, I'm not familiar with this HTML generation with PLSQL.

Comment: well most of the code is PLSQL and at the end is small html code which is only creating a button and a search field for users to submit

Comment: But how do you get inside the page? Is it some "Oracle HTML Technology"? You should go and look for a tutorial here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your HTML isn't complete... you should have something like

```
 <form action="my-next-page.html">
  Student ID:
  <input type="text" name="student_id" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

But here you're only generating the beginning. You probably need to add a little more, like the "form" thing above until the closing tag:

```
htp.BOLD ('Enter the Student ID you wish to unsuspend for the Aspire account');
htp.br;
htp.br;
htp.BOLD ('- PLEASE NOTE Student ID''s that are submitted will be pending unsuspension until the next working day');
htp.p ('<form action="my-next-page.html">');
htp.p (' Student ID: ');
htp.p ('<input type="text" name="student_id" >');
htp.br
htp.p ('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
htp.p ('</form>');
```

And then resulting post should be processed in `my-next-page.html`. But you really should work on an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because here it's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for the late comment. maybe i wasnt clear before. i have a cursor called C_STUDENTS. and i have a form field and button which are in html and plsql in TOAD.  what i'm asking is when the user types in the numbers and clicks submit, my cursor should run. how do i go on about doing this ?