# how do i declare a dbms output variable on plsql?

Tags: plsql

I keep getting this error when trying to compile

> `[Error] PLS-00201 (159: 25): PLS-00201: identifier 'DMBS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE' must be declared`

Here's the faulty code:

```
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STUDENT:'||V_STUDENT||
      'Error Occured: '||SQLERRM ||CHR(10)||'['||
        DMBS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE|‌​|']');

...
```

Comment: It's not `DMBS`. Try using `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`

Comment: i have. EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STUDENT:'||V_STUDENT|| 'Error Occured: '||SQLERRM
        ||CHR(10)||'['||DMBS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE||']');

Comment: Please post the code that you're working with. The magic ball isnt working today

Comment: i have above your reply. all its asking for is me to declare the variable for dmbs_utility.format_error_backtrace and i cant seem to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gurwinder stated, you just have a typo in your code (***`DMBS_UTILITY`*** instead of **`DBMS_UTILITY`**):

Try this:

```
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STUDENT:'||V_STUDENT||
      'Error Occured: '||SQLERRM ||CHR(10)||'['||
        DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE|‌​|']');

...
```

Comment: thank you. i was making a silly mistake its been a long day

Comment: @A.Rahman, you're welcome. You could consider [accept it as a correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: i also have another problem if you could help me sort it out please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068391/how-do-i-get-a-submit-button-to-post-certain-data-onto-another-page-on-pl-sql-af